# Issues with implementation of while_ function based on mpl::eval_if

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

I made the compile-time function which behaves like a while loop. It passes numerical test, but here is an example which causes an error. In the code below you can see the implementation of while_ function, numerical test, and the example. I would like to know why is the error occurs.

```
// Assertion stuff
#include <boost/mpl/assert.hpp>

// To invoke lambdas
#include <boost/mpl/apply.hpp>

// Required for while_
#include <boost/mpl/placeholders.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/identity.hpp>

// For testing stuff
#include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/not.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/list.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pair.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/pop_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/push_front.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/empty.hpp>

// while_ < Pred, Func, Val> - applies Func to Value while Pred on Value holds.

using namespace boost;
using mpl::placeholders::_1;

// while_ implementation:

template
<
  typename Pred,
  typename Func,
  typename Value
>
class while_ {

  template<typename X>
  struct go : mpl::eval_if
    <
      typename mpl::apply<Pred, X>::type,
      go
      <
        typename mpl::apply<Func, X>::type
      >,
      mpl::identity<X>
    > {};

public:
  typedef typename go<Value>::type type;
};

// Numerical test:

typedef mpl::int_<0> zero;
typedef mpl::int_<5> five;

template<typename Num>
struct is_five : is_same<Num, five> {};

template<typename Num>
struct not_five : mpl::not_<is_five<Num> > {};

template<typename Num>
struct inc : mpl::int_<Num::value + 1> {};

typedef while_
  <
    not_five<_1>,
    inc<_1>,
    zero
  >::type five1;

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((is_five<five1>));

// Actual test:

// We are trying to replace contents of the source list
// to the destination list in reversed order.

typedef mpl::list<char, short, int, float, double> Src;
typedef mpl::list<> Dst;

typedef mpl::pair
  <
    Src,
    Dst
  > init_task;

// 'reduce_task' removes the head of source list and
// prepends it to the destination list.
template<typename Task>
class reduce_task {
  // Pattern match task
  typedef typename Task::first  src;
  typedef typename Task::second dst;
  // Reduce
  typedef typename mpl::front<src>::type            head;
  typedef typename mpl::pop_front<src>::type        reduced_src;
  typedef typename mpl::push_front<dst, head>::type updated_dst;
  typedef mpl::pair
    <
      reduced_src,
      updated_dst
    > reduced_task;
public:
  typedef reduced_task type;
};

// Checks whether the task could be reduced:
template<typename Task>
struct can_reduce :
  mpl::not_
    <
      mpl::empty
        <
          typename Task::first
        >
    > {};

BOOST_MPL_ASSERT((can_reduce<init_task>));

// Let's check that after five reduce operations
// the task will became unreduciable:

typedef reduce_task<init_task>::type task1;
typedef reduce_task<task1>::type task2;
typedef reduce_task<task2>::type task3;
typedef reduce_task<task3>::type task4;
typedef reduce_task<task4>::type task5;
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_NOT((can_reduce<task5>));

// We can't achieve the same result by using while_
// becauce the compilation with the code below
// uncommented leads to the long compilation error
// which says in short that the attempt to apply
// mpl::front to the empty list was detected.

/*
typedef while_
  <
    can_reduce<_1>,
    reduce_task<_1>,
    init_task
  >::type reduced_task;
*/

// So, this means that mpl::eval_if do not
// actualy check the can_reduce<_1> predicate
// value and allows to continue caclulation
// at the moment where it should be stoped.

// Why is this going on?

int main() {}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `while (pred()) func();` ?

Comment: Show some code that triggers the error.

Comment: @NeilKirk Not exactly:
while(Pred, Func, X) = if Pred(X)
  then while(Pred, Func, Func(X));
  else X;

Comment: That's not all the relevant code, please provide a compileable example.

Comment: @filmor Allright, I'll load up it on bitbucket today. I'll give an url here.

Comment: That might help but it's not what I meant. I'd like to see a couple of lines of code that I can plug into a compiler (in this case Coliru, an online compiler as I don't have a proper dev machine here). Have a look at http://www.sscce.org/.

Comment: @filmor I guess I made it. I edited question. So now you can copy the code from there and to compile it. I hope it is close to what you have asked for :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is the `::type` in `go<typename mpl::apply<Func,X>::type >`. [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa5fbc5104c07086) seems to work, but I guess that there should be a less clumsy way to achieve the same goal.